# The flow list command doesn't give me the IOUFlow.

Tags: blockchain, corda

[image: Error Message]

I tried the HelloWorld program as per the instructions given in the CORDA docs https://docs.corda.net/hello-world-introduction.html, but it did not work it throws the following error. When I used flow list command it does not show the IOUFlow which I defined inside the App.kt file. Please help.

Comment: Can you look in the "plugins" folder in one of the nodes ? The CorDapps should be installed there - this is how each node determines what to load.

Comment: There is no plugin folder in the kotlin template given https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/tree/release-V1/cordapp/src/main. But we can find the plugin folder when we clone the example template. Am I right ? I have used the kotlin template to build from scratch

Answer (score 0):

What Cordapp did you install? Looks like you didn't install the IOU one but only the basic Corda one.

p.s. 
docs.corda.net/hello-world-running.html did you compile all the steps with gradle?

Comment: Yes the compilation and build went successful. And I downloaded the template from this link https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin/tree/release-V1/cordapp/src/main. There is only one file App.kt where I make all my changes as per the document. Should I take a different approach ?